# requesting a specific Elastic IP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ip

While requesting for a new elastic IP, can we specify/enter an IP.

The reason is I had an IP earlier, but I accidentally removed that from my AWS account. is there a way, I can get that IP back to my AWS account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that will not be possible. Are you sure you removed it from your account and not just de-allocated it? If you have removed it, then the IP would have gone into the pool and could be used by someone else already.

On a side note, to avoid such issues in the future, it would be best to base your solution around DNS CNAME entries rather than IP addresses. Route 53 can help with this. GoDaddy and other products work as well, however Route 53 updates the DNS table much faster and can be integrated into your solution via APIs if you require it to. Of course this is if your solution can work with CNAMEs rather than IP Addresses.

Answer (score 3):

You Can, as per new announcement from AWS, you can recover your released accidentally released EIPs using AWS-CLI

[Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) now allows customers to recover accidentally released EIPs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/amazon-virtual-private-cloud-vpc-now-allows-customers-to-recover-accidentally-released-eips/)